# Convert object to JSON in serverside JavaScript aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, json-serialization

My application uses serverside JavaScript in aspx files on IIS 8 (Windows 2012R2) .
I want to convert a javascript hash to JSON.

My file test.aspx:

```
<%@language="javascript" Debug="true"%>
<%
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

var header =
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "HS256"
};

var str = serializer.Serialize(header);
Response.Write(str);
%>
```

Result: `["typ","alg"]`
Expected result: `{"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}`

Why does the `JavaScriptSerializer` not work as expected?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you expect that serializer.Serialize(header) returns header?

Comment: I expect it to return the string `'{"typ":"JWT","alg":"HS256"}'` (added quotes for clarification)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavascriptSerializer, which is a server component, will work inside client code.

Probably you'll have better results just using

```
var str = JSON.stringify(header);
```

instead of

```
var str = serializer.Serialize(header);
```

Comment: I am running serverside code, this has nothing to do with client code.

On the server there is no JSON object: JS1135: Variable 'JSON' has not been declared

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that the input you're sending to Serialize is a JS object and maybe this class is not prepared to deal with it (as it surely expects a .NET object).